Error output from Process empty when error occurs
I'm trying to wrap some defaults read and defaults write commands into a macOS tool. I figured I could use the Process to run the tool and capture the output:
func runDefaultsCommand(arguments: [String]) -> String? {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/defaults")
    process.arguments = arguments
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    process.standardError = pipe
    
    do {
        try process.run()
        
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        
        process.waitUntilExit()

        return output
    } catch {
        print("Failed to run defaults command: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

This works great when the defaults was executed successfully, but when I for instance disable Full Disk Access for the tool, the com.apple.Safari cannot be read, but the error is not returned. I would expect similar behavior to the Terminal execution output:
defaults read com.apple.Safari
2024-10-13 23:18:40.609 defaults[13902:2346228] 
Domain /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari does not exist

How come my standardError does not contain any such message? How can I capture that output?
